# Vim-YouCompleteMe-Java: jump to declaration in dependencies

Tags: java, maven, vim, eclipse-jdt, youcompleteme

I am trying to use vim + YCM (jdt.ls) for my java project (maven). Looks setup is correct (at least no error in YCMDebugInfo)

Is it possible to Jump to declaration (`:YCMCompleter GoToDeclaration`) for a class/method which is a dependency that is downloaded to the maven repo? The pop-up however is able to gather methods from the dependencies but I am not able to jump to the declaration.

The error I get is:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot jump to location
```

Comment: trying to do the same thing here, my guess is the repositories in ~/.m2 only contain .jar files and not the source code..hence jdt.ls is unable to find it. Please share if you've found a workaround, thanks!

Comment: @ShideFoo I haven't found a workaround yet. You can have ```java.maven.downloadSources': True``` in ```.ycm_extra_conf.py``` to have sources download in .m2 repo, but still it won't work.

Comment: Hmm the strange thing is that GetDoc or GetType works for me, only jumping to see the method body results in a RuntimeError

Comment: @ShideFoo I have the same issue. Have you found a solution meanwhile?

Comment: motivated by [this function](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core/src/org/eclipse/jdt/ls/core/internal/handlers/MapFlattener.java#L130), I've tried to provide a flattened config structure with `{ 'java': { 'maven': { 'downloadSources': True } } }` in the `.ycm_extra_conf.py`. But still no success. 

But with updating and recompiling vim and ycm, I now get docs shown for the method/variable/type etc. at current cursor position which is already extremely helpful :)